# Specific letters that have each specific colors?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift-playground, generics

I'm wondering if there is a way to make letters in every word colored using the Swift programming language. I'm looking for ideas and leads.

Example:

```
println("This is a string")
```

would look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqxCh.png]

Just incase this helps, I have found other languages that are capable of coloring each letter specifically with a color through javascript and microsoft word.  I am out of leads, any would help. Thanks!

Examples: 
https://superuser.com/questions/230665/how-do-i-change-the-font-color-of-a-specific-letter-throughout-the-entire-ms-wor
[Is there any clean CSS method to make each letter in a word a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155584/is-there-any-clean-css-method-to-make-each-letter-in-a-word-a-different-color)

Comment: No problem, just use an NSAttributedString and give each character a different color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591379/multiple-colors-in-a-uilabel

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26726865/341994 and notice the illustration: some letters have different colors. Yours is just an extreme case! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `UILabel` named `myLabel`:

```
let str = "This is a string"
let colors:[UIColor] = [
    .blackColor(),     // T
    .darkGrayColor(),  // h
    .lightGrayColor(), // i
    .grayColor(),      // s

    .clearColor(),     //

    .redColor(),       // i
    .greenColor(),     // s

    .clearColor(),     //

    .blueColor(),      // a

    .clearColor(),     //

    .cyanColor(),      // S
    .yellowColor(),    // t
    .magentaColor(),   // r
    .orangeColor(),    // i
    .purpleColor(),    // n
    .brownColor(),     // g
]

let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
for (chr, color) in Zip2(str, colors) {
    attrStr.appendAttributedString(
        NSAttributedString(string: String(chr), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color])
    )
}

myLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```